# Debian/Ubuntu r-base-*, r-cran-*, revolution-r packages: porting to ArchLinux

Tags: r, ubuntu, debian, porting, archlinux

Recently I've migrated to Arch Linux, after ~4 years being loyal to Ubuntu. Everything works like a charm, it's noticeably faster than Ubuntu, IMHO it's easier to customise, but when it is to do with support for R, well, Ubuntu takes a medal. I'm not willing to do another distro-shuffle and switch back to Ubuntu, while Debian is just "too stable" for my taste... so I'll stick with Arch for now.

Bunch of R packages available from Ubuntu's universe and/or multiverse repos (like r-cran-* and revolution-r) are not available in Arch. Of course, you can always install packages within R with `install.packages`, but there are dozens of Debian/Ubuntu R packages, and excuse me for saying this, but it's painstaking job to track them down. `r-cran-lattice` can be replaced with `install.packages("lattice")`, but what about `revolution-r` (`revolution-mkl`)? I'd like to have RA optimizations in Arch.

Could you, please, give me some advice about this one? What's the catch? `r-core`, `r-base-dev`, `r-base-core-dbg`, `r-base-core-ra`... Actually, I have two questions:

- What's the difference between these (`r-base-*`)
  packages and "standard" R
  installation?
- And how can I port Debian/Ubuntu packages to Arch (I'm
  talking only about those packages
  that don't come bundled with an official installation, like `r-cran-*` and Revolution-R-like packages)?

It would be nice if *Arch*-ers could have out-of-the-box support for R, like Debian, Ubuntu, Suse and Fedora users. I know it's manageable, I just want to know how hard it is.

Comment: I have a theory.... Anytime someone says they migrated from X to Y, everything is noticeably faster.  My theory is that if you have, say, three flavors of the same program, A B and C, in order to double the speed of A, you migrate from A to B, then B to C, then from C back to A.  By this means, you grow the speed of A exponentially, and therefore after a few rounds the speed of A surpasses the speed of light, and you can divide by zero.

Comment: @Will, if I were you, I'd put a copyright on that one! =)

Comment: With noticeably faster, do you mean the core of the OS, or the GUI stuff? I use mostly ubuntu-server and don't experience any noticeable overhead from the OS when using R.

Comment: @Jeroen I meant about OS `per se`. I should perform some tests, though... (but OTR Arch is better, faster, and more reliable than Ubuntu! there... I've said it out loud!)

Comment: @Jeroen It just has no clutter. At all, to the point you have to install dbus and X on your own (if you need it, of course).

Comment: Ubuntu Server edition is pretty clean by itself as well. And as said, I have never noticed any serious overhead from this 'clutter', and it is convenient when you need it.

Comment: @mbq that is true, but personally, I'd rather not use my Arch machine as a server... In that case I'd probably stick with Ubuntu.

Comment: @Jeroen Sure this doesn't matter on a workstation or server -- but on laptop, boot time and power stuff is important. However I also use Arch on workstation and server machines because of its ultra-fast package and robust package manager, session-independent network manger and configuration files that are not changed by some retard-friendly GUIs.

Comment: @mbq amin, though `pacman` knows to hog if you have large package database, and these days I noticed that it takes too much time to boot. But definitely, Arch has put and end to my distro shuffling habits. And boy do I love when we go off topic and discuss which one is better: `A` or `B`? =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick ones:

- *Debian is just "too stable"* is true only if you only look at Debian stable -- but you could pick Debian testing (as I do) which gets updated packages on a daily basis once they lasted for ten days on unstable. This works for me and has been for over a decade (!!). You also get cran2deb and 2400+ binary r-cran-* deb packages (currently i386 only)
- *difference between `r-base-*` and "standard" R*: none. I try hard to maintain these packages without deviances, yet you get little extras like tab completion etc
- *port from Arch*: no idea, as Debian (and Ubuntu) work for me

In short, looks like you picked something different and now seem to notice it is different (as in "less complete support for R").

Comment: Thanks for replying. I wanted to get more info about Revolution Analytics MKL. It's not that simple as `install.packages()`, or is it? Can you please give me some guidance on this one?

Comment: Ubuntu-only = not-available-on-Debian?

Comment: Again, damn, I say. Thanks for the info, I've posted a question on launchpad, maaaybe I'll get lucky one day! =)

Comment: @aL3xa: why don't you contact Revolution R for info about getting Revolution-R packaged for Arch ... ?

Answer (score 1):

Install dpkg in Arch (from AUR, best with yaourt) and you can go.